# Unidirectional ManyToMany joined by another entity

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have items, weblinks and categories. Item has a Weblink and Weblink has a Category:

```
/** @Entity */
class Item {
    /**
      * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Weblink", inversedBy="items")
      */
    private $weblink;
}

/** @Entity */
class Weblink {
    /**
      * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="weblinks")
      */
    private $category;

    /**
      * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Item", mappedBy="weblink")
      */
    private $items;
}

/** @Entity */
class Category {
    /**
      * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Weblink", mappedBy="category")
      */
    private $weblinks;
}
```

So far so good. Now I would like to introduce a `Category::$items` field, that will contain all the items, that have weblink of this category.

I tried to use unidirectional ManyToMany, but it fails, because it tries to create again the already existing join table (it is the table of Weblink entities):

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Item")
 * @JoinTable(name="weblink",
 *      joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id") },
 *      inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="weblink_id") }
 *      )
 */
private $items;
```

Is there a way to map such a relationship?

Comment: I think you don't understand how to describe associations for Doctrine2. If `items` has many `weblinks` and `weblinks` has many categories, you should describe them as `oneToMany`...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly there really is no need to map that relationship. It already exists in your mapping. When you want all the items contained in a category when given a category you can simply obtain them by writing:

```
$category_id = $id;
$oCategory = $entityManager->find('Category', $category_id);
$items = $oCategory->getWeblinks()->getItems();
```

with in your Category entity:

```
public function getWeblinks(){
     return $this->weblinks;
}
```

and in the Weblink entity

```
public function getItems(){
     return $this->items;
}
```